# How to make a button click open a html page in a chrome extension popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension pop-up and want to open "settings.html" on click of the settings button in popup.html

here is the code which I am trying but nothing happens when I click on the settings button.

**popup.html**

```
</div>
    <div class="buttons"><a href="settings.html"></a><button class="button">Settings</button></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your `<a>` tag is empty. You need to add some text right before `</a>`. Or move `</a>` after `</button>`. Use devtools to inspect your actual DOM: right-click the popup, then click "inspect".

Comment: Moving  `</a>` after the button worked. Thanks! can you please also elaborate why it wasn't working. Also, the settings page gets opened in the popup itself, is there any way I can make it open in a new tab? Thanks again!

Comment: Add `target="_blank" ` before `href`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I am a beginner at this so would you mind telling me where should I study this stuff because I seem to be having a lot of such problems.